# Insert Filename Headers into Numerous XLSX files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm very new to the world of VBA, but I need a VBA script to insert the filename as a footer into Excel. Ideally, I would like to insert the first 7 characters of the filename into the footer of each tab in an excel files.

I have about 5000 Excel files that need this macro. I've only ever been able to insert headers/footers into each worksheet and all tabs (not multiple files) using the following code:

```
Sub InsertHeaderFooter()    
' inserts the same header/footer in all worksheets

  Dim ws As Worksheet   
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Application.StatusBar = "Changing header/footer in " & ws.Name    
    With ws.PageSetup    
      .RightFooter = "&"    
    End With

  Next ws

  Set ws = Nothing    
  Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, i meant &[File]. The excel sheets are all in one location.

Comment: Did the answer below help you enough to get it done? Could you consider accepting the answer or indicating what roadblocks you encountered? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Plain `&` doesn't work for me in Excel 2007; maybe you meant `&[File]` or maybe `&` is a shorthand in newer versions?

Regarding the 5000 files, you'll probably want to make sure they're all in the same location and then loop through all .xlsx files in that location. (Do you need to filter based on file name as well?)

If you google `multiple files excel vba` I think you'll find the 3rd hit and following to be relevant. Some key elements from the MSDN article:

```
' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\Peter\invoices\"

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""

    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    ' DO WORK

    ' DO SAVE CHANGES
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=True

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```

If you need to drill down into subdirectories, consider splitting the whole Do While loop out into a Sub that calls itself recursively (and passing the folder location in as a parameter). Googling `vba loop through folder tree` ... See the recursive answer on [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/macro-loop-through-all-subfolders/605972b8-f8f1-4719-9e02-fd79b32ea68e)

Comment: TIP: programming questions will probably get better answers on stackoverflow. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba .  Also,  I find that in MS Office you can first record a macro and then go tweak the VB code that it produces (Alt+F11). Or better, record it and then copy just the relevant macro lines into a new macro, since the recorded one will be way more verbose/specific than you need.